# PyCharm can't find paho library

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, paho

I just installed PyCharm on my windows machine. Running Python 2.7.10, I have a module with the line

```
import paho.mqtt.client as client
```

I get the 'No module named paho' error.  I've installed pip and paho on my Python27 installation on the host but PyCharm has not found it.

How do I import the paho library into PyCharm?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJ9bTO5yYw0
```

File:Settings:Project:Project Interpreter, click '+' in upper right corner, scroll to paho.mqtt, select and click 'Install Package'

Could not be easier - thanks to all.